# CssStyleCollection Class : access properties through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I access CssStyleCollection class properties ( most of all I interesting its key-value collection) using reflection?

```
// this code runns inside class that inherited from WebControl
PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();

//I'am not  able to do something like this
  foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
  {
     if(property.Name == "Style")
     {
        IEnumerable x = property.GetValue(this, null) as IEnumerable;
        ...
     }
  }
```

Comment: When you run the foreach loop does it ever find "Style" make sure that it's not "style"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the syntax for getting the `Style` property via reflection:

```
PropertyInfo property = GetType().GetProperty("Style");
CssStyleCollection styles = property.GetValue(this, null) as CssStyleCollection;
foreach (string key in styles.Keys)
{
    styles[key] = ?
}
```

Note that [`CssStyleCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.cssstylecollection.aspx) doesn't implement IEnumerable (it implements the indexing operator), so you can't cast it to that.  If you want to get an IEnumerable, you could extract the keys using `styles.Keys`, and the values:

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = styles.Keys.OfType<string>();
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> kvps 
    = keys.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(key, styles[key]));
```

Comment: yes,its work.My mistake was that I tryed to do direct cast (CssStyleCollection)... or treat as Ienumerable when its not Imlemented this interface.